# Fastify reply view with JSON object from filtered array

Tags: arrays, json, ejs, fastify

I want to return a view with data that has been filtered from a JSON array based on the URL in the GET request.

Using Fastify I have a GET route that handles the pages under blog for example example.com/blog/blogPageTitle.

And I use the incoming url title to filter an array posts that are in a json file (posts.json), and return the view using the point-of-view fastify plugin:

```
const posts = require('./../posts.json')

fastify.get('/blog/:urlTitle', async (request, reply) => {
    // e.g. request.params.urlTitle = "blogPageTitle"
    let data = posts.filter(items => items.urlName === request.params.urlTitle)       
     
    reply.view('/templates/workItem.ejs', data)
    
})
```

posts.json JSON file I am filtering:

```
[
 {
  urlName: 'blogPageTitle-1',
  title: 'Post title 1',
  subTitle: 'blah blah blah',
  tags: [
    'history',
    'geography',
    'another theme'
  ]
 },
 {
  urlName: 'blogPageTitle-2',
  title: 'Post title 2',
  subTitle: 'blah blah blah',
  tags: [
    'history'
  ]
 },
 {
  urlName: 'blogPageTitle-3',
  title: 'Post title 3',
  subTitle: 'blah blah blah',
  tags: [
    'maths'
  ]
 }
]
```

The variable data is returning an array with a single object:

```
[
  {
    title: 'Post title',
    subTitle: 'blah blah blah',
    tags: [
      'history',
      'geography',
      'another theme'
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to return just the object, rather than the array > object.

In my EJS template page I have the following:

```
<h1><%= title %></h1>
<h2><%= subTitle %></h2>
<ul>
    <% tags.forEach(tag => { %>
     <li><%= tag %></li> 
    <% }) %>
</ul>
```

I get a 500 error from EJS stating that the <%= title %> is not defined. If I put this as <%= data.title %> then this seems to work, however I don't want to have to access the arrayed object on a page.

I have two questions:

1. Is this the best way to search through the json to get the single related post?
2. How do I return just an object with the post data, rather than an array?

Comment: `posts.filter` should be `posts.find`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want to be using the [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method. This filters a list and finds the first matching object or `undefined` if there are no matches.

In your example:

```
const posts = require('./../posts.json')
fastify.get('/blog/:urlTitle', async (request, reply) => {
    // e.g. request.params.urlTitle = "blogPageTitle"
    const data = posts.find({ urlName } => urlName.includes(request.params.urlTitle))       
     
    reply.view('/templates/workItem.ejs', data) 
})
```

Should return the first `post` whose title contains the `urlTitle` from the `request.Params`.